# Unable to upload audio to the server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, multipartform-data, cloudinary

I am able to upload audio locally. But uploading audio to the server is not working. My code is:

```js
module.exports.uploadAudio = function (req, res) {
    var form = new multiparty.Form();

    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
        console.log("Audio_Path=======>>>> " + JSON.stringify(files.file[0].path));

        cloudinary.uploader.upload(files.file[0].path, function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            obj.key2 = result.url;
            res.send({
                result: result,
                serverStatus: 200,
                response_message: "audio uploaded"
            });
        }, {
            resource_type: "auto"
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Check out StackOverflow Help center on how to ask a good question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have some errors ?

Comment: yes, file path not found and this problem show only MAC OS .

Comment: Code looks fine from "Cloudinary" perspective, can't say much about "Multiparty" side. Did you try to verify the transmitted data?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "video" instead of "auto" for the value of the property "resource_type":

```
cloudinary.uploader.upload(files.file[0].path, function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            obj.key2 = result.url;
            res.send({
                result: result,
                serverStatus: 200,
                response_message: "audio uploaded"
            });
        }, {
            resource_type: "video"
        })
```